# Animation for infinitesimally small ring

Tags: calculus

We all know when finding the area of circle or sphere,we slice it infinitesimally small rings of width $dx$ and flatten that into a rectangle type shape.Though the shape isn't quite rectangular since the inner circumference is $2\pi r$ and the outer circumference is $2\pi(r+dr)$ and so the opposite sides of that rectangle aren't quite equal.But to feel good about infinitesimals,i would like to see that infinitesimal part slowly getting diminished or neglected.Could anyone kindly show a picture or animation for that surpose so that i can be comfortable in using infinitesimals?

Comment: Does it help to calculate the area of a ring exactly? For a disk we have$$\text{area}=\pi(r+dr)^2-\pi r^2 = 2\pi r\, dr + \pi\, dr^2.$$The first term on the right is the area of the rectangle in question. The second term, loosely, is so small (infinitesimal squared) that even _after we add up all the contributions from all rings_, the _total error_ is infinitesimal.

Comment: Thanks,but aren't we using circular logic in this case,you already assumed area of a circle is $\pi r^2$.Also i wanted an animation or gif just to be comfortable:3

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you're asking. <> If we're defining $\pi$ to be the ratio circumference-to-diameter of a circle, Archimedes' dissection of a disk into sectors, i.e., the approximation by inscribed and circumscribed regular polygons, can be used to show the area of a disk of radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$. Then it's possible to proceed as suggested. <> I don't know of a suitable animation offhand, but if you roll an ordinary sheet of paper into a cylinder and take a section perpendicular to the cylinder's axis, the approximation is implicit. (The paper compresses/stretches very slightly!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply,but as lazy as i am,i wanted to see that slight stretch diminishing with an animation :3